# How to create a context menu entry, in windows, to open PowerShell with administrator privileges?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8.1

There is a great [community wiki comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24603961/4634544) that demonstrates adding a context menu entry (though, without admin rights). How would you change the registry keys or the following .reg file to open PowerShell with Administrator privileges?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;
; Add context menu entry to Windows Explorer background
;
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\powershell]
@="Open PowerShell window here"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\powershell\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V'"

;
; Add context menu entry to Windows Explorer folders
;
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\powershell]
@="Open PowerShell window here"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\powershell\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V'"

;
; Add context menu entry to Windows Explorer drive icons
;
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\powershell]
@="Open PowerShell window here"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\powershell\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V'"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set "Run this program as an administrator" programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313045/how-to-set-run-this-program-as-an-administrator-programatically)

Comment: thanks for the response, but I wasn't able to gather much from any of those answers.

Comment: REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "RUNASADMIN" /f

Comment: ^ this would be the command you'd run if you wish to add an entry to the registry. Alternatively, you could add that to your reg file.

Comment: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"="RUNASADMIN"

Comment: That's funny. I was just posting a workaround similar to this. Not a perfect answer but works for me. Thanks Nathan.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround:

Force PowerShell to open as admin every time by adding an entry to registry key located at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\
```

Key name = Path - example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Value Data:

```
RUNASADMIN
```

This isn't exactly how I wanted to do it but it works for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the key **runas** would cause whatever command to run as administrator.
Below you can see part of the registry tweak that I use, or you can see the full *.reg* file I use on my [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/RBotfield/bb3c8a05aa531435b608)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Open elevated PowerShell here"
"Extended"=""
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V'"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\runas]
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
@="Open elevated PowerShell here"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\runas\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V'"
```