# Converting C# Application that runs CMD commands to one that runs Powershell commands with administrative privileges

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd, elevated-privileges

I have a Visual studio Application that runs a series of Cmd commands using the following function

```
public static void AdminEx(string command) //Runs an Administrative Windows Command
    {
        var proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.UseShellExecute = true;
        proc.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
        proc.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
        proc.Verb = "runas";
        proc.Arguments = "/c " + command;
        proc.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

We recently updated our Code and converted to Powershell. How would I go about changing this function to accommodate for the new code. Is this still the most efficient way to go???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Otávio Caldonazo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793045/45375) provides an effective solution, but it's worth explaining a few things:

- Unless there are security concerns (someone having placed a nonstandard, malicious `cmd.exe` / `powershell.exe` executable in a folder listed in the `%PATH%` / `$env:PATH` environment variable that preempts the standard executables), it is **simpler to use the executable *file name* alone, i.e., just `cmd.exe` / `powershell.exe`** - this also avoids problems with non-standard Windows installations whose root is *not* `C:\Windows`.

  - Also, given that **you're specifying a *full path* via `.FileName`, the `.WorkingDirectory` property is effectively *ignored* with `.Verb` set to `runas`**, because `.WorkingDirectory` then doesn't actually *set the working directory*, but specifies *where to find the executable*, if specified *by name only* - however, lookups in `%PATH%` / `$env:PATH` are still performed.
- While the `/c` parameter to pass a command to the shell invoked happens to work with PowerShell's *CLI* too, **PowerShell generally use sigil `-` to prefix parameter names**; thus, 
  `-c` (short for `-Command`) is the better choice.

  - Additionally, given that PowerShell loads its `$PROFILE` initialization file *by default* (even when invoked with `-Command` or `-File`, even though that is generally undesirable), it's **best to use `-NoProfile -Command ...`** instead.
- ***Generally* - if you *don't* need *elevation* (running as an *admin*) - as an alternative to the - slow - creation of a *child process* via `powershell.exe`, consider use of the [*PowerShell SDK (API)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/windows-powershell)**, which enables **faster *in-process* execution** while also enabling **more fine-grained capturing of *output streams*** (which you don't seem to be interested in in your particular scenario; while `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` allows you to capture stdout and stderr output via the `.RedirectStandardOutput` and `.RedirectStandardError` properties, note that PowerShell has [*additional* output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)).

Based on the above, I suggest doing the following:

```
var proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
proc.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.Verb = "runas";
proc.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
proc.Arguments = "-NoProfile -Command " + command;
proc.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
p.WaitForExit();
```

Or, more concisely:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

var proc = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
  UseShellExecute = true,
  Verb = "runas",
  WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
  FileName = "powershell.exe",
  Arguments = "-NoProfile -Command " + command
};
Process.Start(proc).WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Hey, Quick question: I want to change a registry key using the above? how would i go about that?

Comment: @securityghost: The generic `*-Item*` cmdlets allow you to work with the registry, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35228704/45375), for instance. If you need further help, please create a _new_ question; feel free to ping me here once you've done so.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the line:

```
proc.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
```

To:

```
proc.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
```

This will make your software open powershell.exe instead of cmd.exe, I can't tell if that is the best way to go about this but I tried here and it worked for me.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this method, instead you should reference the System.Management.Automation namespace.

Comment: @persistent13 what is the `System.Management.Automation namespace`??? Can you explain what it does and how i could use it?       - Much Appreciated

Comment: Please see the link that elgonzo posted in a comment under your question. System.Management.Automation is PowerShell for use in C#. Instead of having to call an external process you have full programmatic control over the PowerShell instance.

Comment: @Persistent13: While recommending the PowerShell SDK (API) is good pointer in general, there's an added requirement here: the need to run _as admin_ (elevated), which, AFAIK, _invariably_ involves an _external process_, so using securityghost's _child-process_ approach via the Powershell _CLI_ (with `.UseShellExecute` set to `true` and `.Verb` set to `RunAs`) may be the best (only?) approach, after all.